# date.js Parse method overrides Javascript Parse method

Tags: javascript, date, datejs

I'm including the `date.js` library in my site because I need its functionality.

I have just realized, though, that the standard Javascript `parse()` method is overwritten by it.

I'm trying to build a line chart in Highcharts, and the data series wants the first element to be be in milliseconds (their demos show them using the `Date.UTC()` method to achieve this, but my data is returned in a different format).

Short of doing a bunch of string manipulation to put my data into a format that `Date.UTC` will recognize, is there another way of getting the standard Javascript `parse()` functionality while `date.js` is loaded?

Comment: You shouldn't provide an answer in your question. I've put the answer into an actual answer as a community wiki.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this isn't a direct solution to your problem, but it may help anyway.

If you want a fully featured date library that doesn't modify the native `Date` object, I wrote one called Moment.js.

It provides a lot of the things that DateJS provides (formatting, parsing, manipulation, timeago, i18n, etc), but it's smaller, faster, and doesn't ruin the native date prototype.

https://github.com/timrwood/moment

Comment: Finally got it to work, after I discovered that your documentation is a little off - it says to use moment.day(1) to set a date to the 1st, but it should be moment.date(1).

Comment: Note from the authors of moment.js: "_we would like to discourage Moment from being used in new projects going forward_" ([source](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)).

Answer (score 1):

Nope, this is the intended design of date.js.  It adds to the "prototype" of the Date object.  Some people hate that, some people like it - but you've uncovered one of the drawbacks of this design.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Highcharts to not use UTC date:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```

You should do this before you create the chart. Then you won't have to worry about converting your dates to UTC, it will be easier.

Comment: If I do this, I'm not understanding what Highcharts wants to see for a date - an actual Date object? The documentation doesn't specify.

Comment: @earachefl: The date value will be in milliseconds, e.g. if you have a Date object `d` then `d.getTime()` will give you the value of date in milliseconds, that's what you feed to Highcharts, no matter you are using `useUTC: false` or not. The difference is that if you have `useUTC: true`, then you need to convert that date to UTC date first and then get millisenconds and feed to Highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

after I asked the question, I went ahead and did it this way:

```
d = Date.parse(data);
            y = d.getFullYear();
            m = d.getMonth();
            d = d.getDate();
            dUTC = Date.UTC(y, m, d);
```

but will now try your suggestions.