# Breeze dates are not materialized correctly for mapped entities

Tags: javascript, breeze

I have a date property coming into Breeze from my server.  It looks like this in the JSON

```
"CreateTime":"2014-05-22T00:00:00.000"
```

The property is mapped in the metadata like this:

```
{
    "name":"CreateTime",
    "type":"Edm.DateTime",
    "nullable":"false",
    "precision":"7"
}
```

In the query results, however, the date always ends up as the epoch (Jan 1, 1970).  However, this **only** happens when the entity is mapped in Breeze.  If I `select` against the entity so that I am returning an unmapped type the date is sent across the wire identically, but it works fine.

How can I get dates to materialize correctly for mapped entities?

Using Breeze v1.4.11

**Update**

Here is the result of calling `getEntityType` on my entity:

```
{
   "shortName":"VDisplayEvent",
   "namespace":"Model",
   "autoGeneratedKeyType":"None",
   "defaultResourceName":"VDisplayEvents1",
   "dataProperties":[
      // Other properties...
      {
         "name":"createTime",
         "dataType":"DateTime",
         "isNullable":false,
         "defaultValue":"1900-01-01T08:00:00.000Z",
         "validators":[
            {
               "name":"required"
            },
            {
               "name":"date"
            }
         ]
      },
      // Other properties...
   ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't repro this. Can you give a little more detail, and I'd start by investigating the datatype of this date property in your metadataStore, via the MetadataStore.getEntityType method and then drilling into the specific data property.

Comment: @JayTraband, thanks I updated the question with the results from `getEntityType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, and it's not an issue with Breeze.  My application is using a theme, which had a dependency on [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/).  Apparently, date.js [overrides Javascript's `Date.parse()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7934006/546561), which is used by Breeze's `DataType.parseDateAsUTC()`.

Date.js's `Date.parse()` function just returns null when confronted with parsing a date string like the one above, which was causing the issue.

Comment: I get error when i use DataType.parseDateAsUTC() and error is Object doesnt support parseDateAsUTC()